# php sort array keys in multidimensional array

Tags: php, html, arrays, sorting

below is my array

```
$myarray = Array(
[1] => Array (['mytime']=>1),
[7] => Array(['mytime']=>2),
[2] => Array(['mytime']=>3),
[3] => Array(['mytime']=>4)
);
```

I want to sort output of this array based on keys...

```
$myarray = Array(
[1] => Array (['mytime']=>1),
[2] => Array(['mytime']=>3),
[3] => Array(['mytime']=>4),
[7] => Array(['mytime']=>2)
);
```

I have already tried `ksort($myarray)` it displays `1`
anyways to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

[**ksort()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) does this:

```
ksort($myarray);
```

*Note:* sorting functions do not return a new sorted array; they simply sort the array passed, and return true or false. Thus, `ksort($myarray)` will return 1 when successful, and `$myarray` will be sorted.

It's very clear if you read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Comment: i have tried that .. i get out as `1`

Comment: Yes, because ksort returns true on success and false on failure, but the array will still be sorted. Demo: http://codepad.org/tJxzCVGd